# phonegap - Additional Emulator Command Line Options

Tags: eclipse, cordova

I don't have the field "Additional Emulator Command Line Options", but I would like to resize the emulator to 0.5, because I work on laptop and the emulator is very big. How can I solve this in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Try to resize the dialog for you to see "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" field.